# FFmpeg not finding file

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have been experimenting with youtube-dl and have come across a problem when trying to combine the audio and video files youtube-dl downloaded. When I tried to use FFmpeg to merge the files it keeps giving me the error: No such file or directory.

Here is the directory of the files with filenames.

```
Directory of H:\YouTube-DL\Active Scripts\Unique\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304
07/07/2020  03:08 PM    <DIR>          .
07/07/2020  03:08 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/07/2020  03:06 PM             1,742 Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].description
05/23/2020  11:10 AM     1,651,344,242 Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f248.webm
05/23/2020  01:35 AM       190,523,121 Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f251.webm
07/07/2020  03:06 PM            33,001 Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].info.json
07/07/2020  03:06 PM           120,050 Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].webp
               5 File(s)  1,842,022,156 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  3,872,264,060,928 bytes free
```

Here is the command I tried to use in the command prompt. I have used this command before for other files and had no problem, so I'm trying to figure out if there is an error or the filename is too long, etc.

```
H:\YouTube-DL\Active Scripts\Unique>ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" -i "file:Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f248.webm" -i "file:Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f251.webm" -c copy -map "0:v:0" -map "1:a:0" "file:Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].temp.mkv"
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-28-4cfcfb3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 93.100 / 58. 93.100
  libavformat    58. 47.100 / 58. 47.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
file:Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f248.webm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where did you even get the idea of trying to use ffmpeg and youtube-dl like that anyway? Another user tried a similar thing recently. You should just download the file with youtube-dl then use ffmpeg on it. You are blindly following some instructions, you should state what. Maybe similar page to whatever the other guy did

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to using it I started by using some scripts that you can find here: https://github.com/TheFrenchGhosty/TheFrenchGhostys-YouTube-DL-Archivist-Scripts#channels-playlists-and-unique-scripts

Comment: The scripts were just a way to download a video in the best resolution and then download the best audio, and combine them both using FFmpeg. The problem is that certain videos like the one above don't get combined by ffmpeg

Comment: @barlop Would looking at that other users post help me? I'm having trouble finding it, do you have a link?

Comment: @Dalen probably not , was probably a different issue

Comment: @Dalen but if you want to troubleshoot something then use small example files with short names! And have both in the current directory so you don't have a massive path!

Comment: @Dalen You write "I'm trying to figure out if there is an error or the filename is too long, etc. " <-- Would be good if you were but you're not!  If you were then you'd try making a copy of the file with a shorter name!  That's basic troubleshooting and you haven't done it! And you should do that anyway to simplify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggests what is going on. It says

```
file:Your Mom.....webm: No such file or directory
```

And the command you are using, has "file:....webm"  so you put file: in there which you shouldn't have.

I took your line, simplified it by making the filenames smaller so you can see what's going on better. (That's what you should have done, basic troubleshooting!)

And I changed e.g. file:abc.mp4 which you had, that seems to have been wrong and the issue. I changed that to abc.mp4.

So I have this example now.

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" -i abc.mp4 -i def.mp4 -c copy -map "0:v:0" -map "1:a:0" total.mp4
```

That seems to take the video of abc.mp4 and combines it with the audio from def.mp4

The result can be very entertaining actually.  I just tried it for two different talk shows. So it shows the video of abc.mp4 with the voices of def.mp4 !

So for you just try replacing "file:" which you shouldn't have had with nothing.
So try

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" -i "Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f248.webm" -i "Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f251.webm" -c copy -map "0:v:0" -map "1:a:0" "Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].temp.mkv"
```

And if that doesn't work then maybe your filenames or paths are too long.

Comment: I used it without the file: and it still gave me the same error unfortunately

Comment: @Dalen well copy your file to abc.mkv and def.mkv no long path. Also there's no way it'd give the same error 'cos the error you got said "file:........no such file or directory"  so it won't say that when you remove the "file:" Also try running DIR on each of them e.g. `DIR "Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304\Your Mom's House Podcast - Ep. 541 w_ Moshe Kasher & Natasha Leggero & Creators of HBO's McMillions - YourMomsHousePodcast - 20200304 [6QSorNQTJa0].f248.webm"`

Comment: but really copy each file to be  abc.webm  and def.webm   in the current  directory and named like that That's basic troubleshooting

Comment: So renaming worked perfectly! Is there a reason why the process wouldn't work with the files as they were named originally. I'm just wondering because I have multiple files I need to fix and would like to not have to rename them each time I want to combine with FFmpeg

Comment: if they filenames or paths or too long would overriding this restriction in windows work?

Comment: @Dalen well the person at your link struggled with a windows path length limit  "Warning for Windows users: Because Windows is using a path length limit of 260 characters, you might have problems when downloading videos with long title (or even videos with short one if your path is long), supposedly there is ways to disable this limit but during my testing I couldn't make it to work....."    (he then mentions a program for downloading but you downloaded them ok)

Comment: This might help if you are on Windows 10 with the latest update https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/  apparently the windows path restriction can be removed

Comment: I tried to remove it but it doesn't seem to be working for me at least. Thanks for helping me solve the error though!

Comment: @Dalen you could try a batch file script that renames/moves each of the two files to a temporary name, does the command, then renames/moves them back. Then you could run the command  `blahscript "Your muma............mkv"  "your mumb.....mkv"`    And it will sort it out

Comment: Ill have to try that out! Thanks!